# Tracing method/function in xCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods

I am not sure whether it is possible to trace method instead of finding in find navigator. For example,I have

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
```

and I have many other "xmppStream" word in my project. So, tracing that function by word is not quite easy. May I know how to trace back a method quickly? Is it possible?